# Can't dismiss sticky message in Genesis theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, genesis

Please look at the sticky message on website x. When you click on the dismiss button, the page goes to the top and the sticky message is coming back when scrolling down. Any idea how to resolve this issue? I have added the script below in functions.php and the necessary javascript/CSS.

```
// Enqueue Scripts and Styles.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oc_enqueue_scripts_styles' );
function oc_enqueue_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'oc_sticky_message', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/sticky-message.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
}

//* Register widget areas
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'sticky-message',
    'name'        => __( 'Sticky Message', 'oc' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the sticky message section.', 'oc' ),
) );

// Add markup for the sticky message.
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'oc_sticky_message' );
function oc_sticky_message() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'sticky-message', array(
        'before' => '<div class="sticky-message">',
        'after'  => '<a class="dismiss dashicons dashicons-no-alt" href="#"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss</span></a></div></div>',
    ) );
}
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Add reveal class to sticky message after 100px
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) { // Revealed after a person has scrolled 100px down
            $(".sticky-message").addClass("reveal");
        } else {
            $(".sticky-message").removeClass("reveal");
        }
    });
    $('.sticky-message a.dismiss').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents(".sticky-message").addClass("hard-close");
    });
});
```

```
.hard-close {
      display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `script` for `x` button click. It simply directs to the `href=#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `script` lines and `CSS` to your code. I assumed that the close tag has the `dismiss` class as a static one.

CSS

```
.hard-close{
  display:none !important;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.sticky-message a.dismiss').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents(".sticky-message").addClass("hard-close");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, but where to put the script exactly? Whitin the jQuery function or replace the #?

Comment: Within the JQuery function, but outside of the `$(document).on("scroll", function() {});`

Comment: I have changed the code in the initial post the way I have implemented it, but the situation is still the same. Am I doing it wrong or should I change href="#" aswell?

Comment: No, you don't need to. The browser may be cached with the old code. Use CTRL+F5 to refresh and then try

Comment: I just noticed. Add `$` sign before `('.sticky-message a.dismiss')`. So it will be like `$('.sticky-message a.dismiss').click(function(e){`